# How to handle the multiple threads with FMDB Using SQLite In IOS Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3, fmdb

I Want to do Multiple read and write operation with database on background

But when i am trying to do it always showing FMDB is already in use and crashing happens

How to handle the multiple threads run at time FMDB

Please give perfect example of handling DB in IOS Swift Sqlite

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

FMDB won't let you do that unless you strengthen your understanding of SQLite a lot. You can also use a library that does what you need right away, such as http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift. Its DatabasePool class lets you perform concurrent read & write operations.